# Dictionary only print and saves the last item

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a problem, when I try to print all the rows of the csv file, the dictionary only saves and prints the last row. I have tried to figure out what I was doing wrong and I count find an answer.

```
import csv

data = open(r"C:\Desktop\file.csv")
dataReader = csv.reader(data, delimiter = ";")
count = 0
for row in dataReader:
    bookList= dict()
    bookList[row[0]]= row[1]
    print(row)
for k,v in bookList.items():
        print(k,v)
```

Comment: You create multiple different dictionaries...

Comment: move `bookList= dict()` before `for row in dataReader:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because you create a new dictionary instance for each iteration of the loop. Create it once at the beginning, before the loop:

```py
import csv
data = open(r"C:\Desktop\file.csv")
dataReader = csv.reader(data, delimiter = ";")
count = 0
bookList = dict()
for row in dataReader:
    bookList[row[0]]= row[1]
    print(row)
for k,v in bookList.items():
        print(k,v)
```